# showAlert search input and show

Tags: javascript

Hello together someone here help me with that Code its working :

```
function showAlert(){ 
        var dropzone = $('#dropzoneorg').html();
                       $('#dialog span').html(dropzone); 
                       $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true}); 
                    }
```

But now i want to search Inputs in IDs ("#dropzoneorg"..) and than Show me that in Dialog.
Maybe like this, but first he must search if something is inside:

```
function showAlert(){ 
        var dropzone = $('#dropzone,#dropzone1,#dropzone2,#dropzone3......').html();
                       $('#dialog span').html(dropzone); 
                       $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true}); 
                    }
```

And here the Code to test:https://jsfiddle.net/michiffm/e5t1tsaa/4/

I hope someone can help me :)
LG Michi

Comment: sorry but I cannot understand your question, could you please **reformulate it or add specific information of what you want exactly**?

Comment: Have you tried using a `class` name rather than multiple `ID`'s? Then again it might cause an issue with `$('#dialog span').html(dropzone);` Can you share the relevant HTML to go with this please?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the **.html()** ??
 Please read https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp

Comment: Hey sorry about my English i edit it... i want if someone but somthing in dropzoneorg, dropzoneteil,dropzoneref,dropzonedok via Drag and Drop than show me via Dialog a Massage what is inside

Comment: You also have problems with your HTML `id=i"d_seiten_ref "` and you have an extra closing `td` but no opening `"text" id="id_bemerkung_dok1" name="bemerkung_dok1 ">&nbsp;</td>`

Comment: @NewToJS sorry i copy it wrong no everything is working.... my first script is also working but i want that show me all inputs in all IDs(dropzoneorg, dropzoneteil,dropzoneref,dropzonedok)

Comment: Here a Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKeXa.png mabe its easier to understand :) He Show me just the First one

Comment: Can you show how/where `showAlert()` is called please and explain what content you would like to be within the popup dialog please. I might be able to create you a example.

Comment: Maybe you can make use of this? https://jsfiddle.net/e5t1tsaa/ without seeing how you call `showAlert()` and understand how you want to set the content in relation of whatever is triggering the call I cannot give you a solid solution so this example is all I can offer until you explain how you want this to function and display "All" relevant source... like what is calling `showAlert()` and the relation of that call to know what content should be within the dialog.

Comment: Hey Hey thanks for youre Script but thats not i need. He musst search if Files is inside than show me all ....Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/michiffm/e5t1tsaa/4/

Comment: But where does the other content come in? `#dropzone,#dropzone1,#dropzone2,#dropzone3` and what information are you wanting to display? If you need to explain in detail what you wish to achieve because I can only go by what you tell me and so far you aren't explaining enough to help you.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help very much but my english is very mad, because of that i cant good to explain it. https://jsfiddle.net/michiffm/e5t1tsaa/6/   Here in dropzone and dropzone2 are Files inside and in dropzone1 not so now i want that the script show me everything with inputs with one button click

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e5t1tsaa/9/   is it ok ? i was change in this one please check it....Remove alert in script.. i just forget to remove it

Comment: @UrvishPatel wow thanks a lot its working but i dont know what i must delete sorry my javascript is very bad.... He show me first undefined but than is all right :)

Comment: @MichaelÜnver Mention not...keep working.. ;)

Comment: Okay sorrry haha but thanks a lot Master of Javascript :)

Comment: @UrvishPatel I'm freaky i dont saw that :) alert($(this).attr("id"));   How can i cloes thies thread?

Comment: means i cant understand ...you want to remove alert();

Answer (score 0):

try this one

write this js code in your js function and try it

```
function showAlert(){ 
    var dropzone="";
    $("td").each(function() {
        dropzone = dropzone + $(this).html()+" "+"<br>";   
        $('#dialog span').html(dropzone);        
      });
}
```

and include letest .js library file in your code
link:[1]: https://jquery.com/download/